# Testing tool: is there alternative than expect?

Tags: testing

Our current testing is a simple in-house tool which runs the named target, logs its output and compares it with a expected output. The expected output and real output are both text files.

This has an obvious downside, if some changes of line number change which has no function effect is regarded as failure.

We are thinking to use tools like expect to do this, but we like to know if there are some other alternatives. Googling does not return any immediate answers.

Our platform is linux; the users of this tool does not need to write testing code, basically they currently just provide a plain text file of expected result and we should not ask them to write code or some complex form.

Thanks for your inputs.